# Form layout troubles. New to android

Tags: android

I am creating my first robust android application and am having a lot of trouble trying to layout the controls on the main form.

I have a 4 textviews, 1 checkbox, and 1 button. 
Debugging with Galaxy Nexus (4.65 in) but using form screen size of 4 in so I can accommodate to smaller screen sizes with my app.

Whenever I try to move a textview or button all the other controls seems to move in a different spot on their own. Also half of the placement of the buttons gives me a force close when I debug. It seems like it shouldnt be this hard to lay out controls but then again I come from winforms and very little asp.net.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Edit: Added xml. I have tried width/height of wrap, match parent, and custom sizes with all the same result. Maybe my controls should be in some sort of table like asp.net?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#808080" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:onClick="onOKclicked"
    android:text="@string/OkButton" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkShow"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnOK"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:text="@string/DoNotShow"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt3G"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/chkShow"
    android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
    android:text="@string/Description3G"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt4G"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txt3G"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/chkShow"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:text="@string/Description4G"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/Instructions1"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtBattery"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txt3G"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt3G"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnOK"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:text="@string/DescriptionBattery"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your XML file, it might make it easier for people to help you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with relative layout and when you move a button the layout breaks for controls that are placed relative to that button.

Why you get debugging problems, I don't know. Could you post the stack trace or something helpful?

Comment: It looks like there error I get is... Unable to start activity CompnonetInfo. Java class exception: android.widget.textview cannot be cast to a android.widget.checkbox

Comment: Please post your activity code including the declarations at the top and onCreate().  Also, it is not strictly an error but it is bad practice.  Change android:layout_above="@+id/btnOK" ---> android:layout_above="@id/btnOK" notice no plus.  @id+/ says create a new ID, @id/ references an existing one.

Comment: Appearently you are trying to assign a textview to a checkbox variable. More than that I can't say without looking at the code.